# Dynamic Programming - Bridge crossing

Tags: dynamic-programming

Assume that the edge labels are likelihood as percentage of a bridge collapsing when the crossing is attempted shown in the picture below.

[image: Figure 1.]

1. Find the Probability of survival for each leg in the network and draw the 
   network with these probabilities shown.
2. Solve the DP to find the safest route from 1 to 6

My attempted solution is the following where the blue line indicates the safest route from 1 to 6 and the values are probability of moving from node i to node 6

[image: Figure 2]

I'm not sure if my working is correct so any insights on how to proceed or start would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to compute the highest or Max Probability of Survival reaching to a node n  - call it P(n). Call $PS(A,B)$ as Probability of survival from node A to B. So, 
$$P(6) = Max\{P(4), P(5), P(2), P(3)\}$$
$$P(4) = Max\{P(2), P(3)\}$$
$$P(5) = Max\{P(2), P(3)\}$$
$$P(2) = 0.8, P(3) = 0.75$$
$$P(5) = Max\{PS(2, 5)*P(2), PS(3,5)*P(3)\}
       = Max\{0.8*0.8, 0.8*0.75\}
       = 0.64$$
Best path is from 2 to 5.

Similarly $$P(4) = 0.6$$
Path 1->3->4.

So, $$P(6) = Max\{ PS(4,6)* P(4),
                   PS(5,6)*P(5), 
                   PS(2,6)*P(2),
                   PS(3,6)*P(3) \}$$
    $$P(6) = 0.465$$

So 1->3->6 is the Best path with highest Probability of Survival.